# Javascript converte string para int quando passado como parametro de função

Tags: javascript, funções

tenho o seguinte trecho:

```
"onclick=relatorio("+dados[i].cnpj+")"
```

*dados[i].cnpj* é uma variável do tipo String, ou pelo menos preciso que ela seja assim, porém o JavaScript converte o parâmetro de função em um tipo number logo:

```
function relatorio(cnpj) {
     console.log(cnpj);
}
```

problema: quando preciso fazer um  ajax para o banco, os valores diferem
pergunta: O que poderia fazer pra garantir que dados[i].cnpj continuasse com o tipo string?

[image: Resultado de console.log]

> Não tenho permissão, do cliente para divulgar CNPJs então foi censurado mesmo, mas como se pode ver ai o zero a esquerda foi concatenado quando o tipo de dado foi alterado

Comment: Alem da resposta do Wallace, você também pode dentro de sua função usar o `cnpj.toString()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É porque a sua concatenação torna o valor passado como um inteiro na expressão.

Ou seja, supondo que o valor de `dados[i].cnpj` seja uma string `"1046"`, ao montar a expressão `"onclick=relatorio("+dados[i].cnpj+")"` por meio de concatenação, você está gerando isso:

```
onclick=relatorio(1046)
```

Se você forçar o reconhecimento como string, poderia resolver o problema:

```
"onclick=relatorio('"+dados[i].cnpj+"')"
```

As aspas faria que a expressão fosse montada assim:

```
  onclick=relatorio('1046')
```

Na minha opinião, o ideia seria que você evitasse essas *concatenações malucas*, que costumam confundir bastante.

Daria pra armazenar num atributo `data-cnpj` por exemplo e recuperá-lo

```
"<button data-cnpj='" + dados[i].cnpj + "' onclick='relatorio(this.dataset.cnpj)'></button>"
```

A vantagem do `dataset` é que geralmente, ele sempre retorna `String`.

```html
<button onclick="console.log(this.dataset)" data-cnpj="0000000000111">
 Clica em mim!
</button>
```

Comment: Obrigado, as vezes depois de horas programando deixo pequenos detalhes como esse passar, mas fico grato pela dica do atributo, isso deixa os dados mais claros pra futuras manutenções

Comment: @LeonardodaSilva ok. Eu sempre procuro ir pelo caminho que eu não vou me confudir depois, kkkkk. E sim, depois de horas programando, ao invés do código bugar, quem buga somos nós.